# Software Sources GUI in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation, kubuntu, gui, 18.04, software-sources

I like the good-old Software Sources interface (some sources are seen only there in fact), but it seems that it is absent in Kubuntu 18.04 (cannot find it in the launcher anyway).

I remember that in Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome/Budgie it was absent but I was able to install it back.

How to get it back in Kubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.desktop` file for `Software Sources` is  `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-kde.desktop` in Kubuntu 18.04 but if you open the file with a text editor, you'll see a line with:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

One can comment out that line (and do so each time the package is updated). Alternatively, one could copy over the `.desktop` file over to `~/.local/share/applications` and make the change in the copied file.

Whichever way is chosen, `Software Sources` can be seen in the launcher under `System`:

[image: Launcher]

Or, it can be accessed via `krunner`:

[image: Krunner]

Either way, when launched, you'll be prompted for your user password.

To find a clue as to why this application's `.desktop` file has `NoDisplay` by default, I ran `apt-get changelog python3-software-properties > sof-pro-kde.txt`. In there, way back in `Karmic Koala`, there is this:

```
software-properties (0.75.4) karmic; urgency=low

  * Suffix software-properties.desktop with -gtk.desktop
  * Create a copy of that file with suffix -kde.desktop
    + Change to KDE icon and exec
    + Add NoDisplay=true, the desktop file is only necessary for kdesudo to 
      have it show a proper name and icon which does not require it to show
      up anywhere
```

Comment: `kate /usr/share/applications/software-properties-kde.desktop` also allows to have it changed

Comment: True, but if `kate` is updated as it probably will if you install the `kubuntu-backports` ppa you'll need to make that change each time. That's why I prefer editing a local copy. Note that the `kubuntu-backports` ppa doesn't yet have new stuff like plasma 5.13 for Bionic.

Comment: on plasma 5.13: tested it in Neon itself and even there kwin crashed after a few minutes. No way I'll install that in Kubuntu after all.

Comment: For some reason adding new key doesn't work: NameError: name 'KUrl' is not defined - https://askubuntu.com/q/1079793/47206

Answer (score 7):

It is already installed but is not seen by the launcher by default. **In order to make it visible, follow [the other answer posted by DK Bose.](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036050/47206)**

It can be launched with the command

```
sudo -H software-properties-kde
```

as suggested in a comment by @DKBose

Or, through the Kubuntu's Software -Center (Discover), clicking Settings and the upper-right button

[image]

[image]

---

After having installed LXQT desktop (on top of Kubuntu), what I prefer now is to use the `lxqt-sudo` tool in the `Exec` line of the `.desktop` file  `/usr/share/applications/software-properties-kde.desktop`.

```
Exec=lxqt-sudo software-properties-kde
```

which shows the window with Qt-GUI (the Qt widget style of KDE/LXQT set under the LXQT settings) instead of GTK.

[image]

It seems that `lxqt-sudo` has that effect only in LXQT, and not in KDE/Plasma.

Comment: `sudo -H software-properties-kde` maybe preferable to `sudo software-properties-kde
` since it's a graphical application.

Comment: @DKBose - thanks for pointing it out: it's in the answer now.

Comment: The same is true in 20.04

Comment: @DKBose - what about `pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY software-properties-kde`

Answer (score 2):

In Kubuntu 20.04 LTS, you can find Software Sources by:

1. Launching Discover
2. Clicking "Settings"
3. Clicking "Software Sources"

[image]

You now have opened Software Sources:

[image]

Comment: In fact that was available in 18.04 too. Also, the other answers about 18.04 are valid for 20.x

Answer (score 0):

As a complementary answer:

Right click on the application launcher (dashboard, menu) on the panel, select "Edit Applications"

[image]

Select new item.

[image]

Add a name, icon, and the command

`pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY software-properties-kde`

Save.