# Cannot add PPA key in 18.04: NameError: name 'KUrl' is not defined

Tags: 18.04, software-sources

I am trying to add a ppa key trough *Software Sources - Authentication - Import key file*.

I have solved access to Software Sources interface as described here: [Software Sources GUI in Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036001/software-sources-gui-in-kubuntu-18-04/1036002#1036002).

But launching the tool in terminal and trying to add the key nothing happens.

[image]

This is what is seen in terminal:

```
~$ sudo -H software-properties-kde
[sudo] password for cip: 
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/kde/SoftwarePropertiesKDE.py", line 667, in add_key_clicked
    url = KUrl.fromPath(home)
NameError: name 'KUrl' is not defined
```

I'm in LXQT installed on top of Kubuntu 18.04, the same happens in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be with this chunk of code:

```
home = QDir.homePath()
if "SUDO_USER" in os.environ:
    home = os.path.expanduser("~%s" % os.environ["SUDO_USER"])
url = KUrl.fromPath(home)
```

I tested in a VM and this appears to be a bug with `KUrl` not existing, whatever it's supposed to be. I thought at first it might have something to do with running it from the terminal instead of the GUI method, but I tested those methods as well and still get the same error. Also, reading the code, I don't think it's possible that `KUrl` was defined anywhere or imported as a python module.

I took it upon myself to file this bug in the `software-properties` repository for Ubuntu:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1795278

I suggest for the time being you use the `apt-key add <file>` command to add the key to your system.