# Update frequency setting in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, updates, kubuntu

[Opening Software Sources in Kubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036001/47206) I have selected only important and recommended updates, set the checking for updates only every two weeks and only notify.

[image]

But I still get updates notifications all the time, sometimes even more than once a day.

Am I missing something?

Comment: See https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/74803-Software-update-freuency-setting-is-ignored?p=423465&viewfull=1#post423465.

Comment: I happened to follow the link and I am reading now. I quote relevant text here: "Software properties setting is a holdover from the old apt based update mechanism. The icon/updater you see uses package kit and frequencies for checking updates are coded in, without user facing options. :/"

Comment: But the last comment dated 2018-12-06 in the forum thread reads: "Hey, looks like the dev has already fixed it, wow! https://phabricator.kde.org/D17375" P.S.: Following this link noted the fix is included in 5.14.

Comment: @DKBose - I get `Error 503 : Service Temporarily Unavailable` at that link.

Comment: @clearkimura - That must mean that update frequency settings is not available. Any other way to set frequency except that GUI? - As for `fix is included in 5.14`: 5.14 is already in 18.10, but I will stay with the LTS.

Comment: @cipricus Sorry, I am not aware of how KDE Plasma works; I never had this issue on GTK+ desktop (at least on Xfce). Given that KDE Plasma 5.12 is an LTS release, the fix may be backport from 5.14 but this is just a speculation.

Comment: @DKBose - that is odd. But I gather there is no solution for 5.12.

Comment: @DKBose - I will stay with LTS anyway. Thanks.

Comment: The inability to access kubuntuforums.net maybe related to VPN usage: https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/73662-Can-t-access-the-forum-using-some-VPNs?p=424708&viewfull=1#post424708

Comment: @DKBose - not the case here. it's some freak event related maybe to my ip (in which not i or my machine is peculiar, but rather my internet provider or more probably that website). The result in FF and Chrome it's the same today, and looks funny: https://pasteboard.co/HXjhzyk.png While https://www.kubuntuforums.net/ gives me "Error 503 : Service Temporarily Unavailable"

Comment: Your image mentions ZB Block which is what that forums uses.

Answer (score 0):

Believe it or not, try this:

- right-click the upward pointing triangle on the system tray, next to the clock
- select *System Tray Settings*
- in the *General* tab, under *Extra Items*, deselect *Updates*
- save the settings with *Apply* or *OK*

Comment: Does this actually change the update interval or just hide the notifications? I thought the intention of the OP was to have less frequent updates.

Comment: For me, it actually stopped those automatic updates every time I booted my machine, which was what I wanted.