# Assistance needed with: The repository cdrom://... does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates

Why do I continue to receive this error message:

```
The repository 'cdrom://Kubuntu 20.04.3 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20210819.1) focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

...and just exactly how does one go about correcting it?

Any information provided on the issue at hand is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Open [Software Sources](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036002/124466), and uncheck the Kubuntu CDROM.

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a user forum. So the "I require assistance" header is less appropriate. Please update the title of your question to reflect the problem. Please also clarify the question. Unclear how "printf" is related here. What do you do to have the error message?

Comment: I see. So, the original way I chose to word my question( which was basic and direct) I was told to make my question more "specific". Of which it was, or so I thought. I asked the question as if I was speaking to someone in hopes that they would be able to help me out. That didn't suffice, so on impulse, I quickly re-worded the question, so that it would be accepted. As for "printf", it has no relation here. It simply was a humorous way to format my greeting. Finally, what I did to warrant the error message was: sudo apt-get  update && sudo apt-get upgrade. Thank you both for the quick reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by **[Archisman Panigrahi](https://askubuntu.com/users/124466/archisman-panigrahi)**, You need to open the software and update app and disable the CDrom repository.

1. Open the software sources file known as `sources.list`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. Find the line which looks similar to:

   ```
   deb cdrom:[Ubuntu Desktop <version> <codename> - x86] <code name> <reponames>
   ```

   Most likely it will be the first line.
3. Comment the line by putting a `#` after it.

   ```
   # deb [<foo> <foo> blah blah whatever] foobar whatever...
   ```

   You can also remove the line if you want.
4. Run update:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

Alternatively, you can change the `/etc/apt/sources.list` to:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
```

And run `apt update`:

```
sudo apt update
```

An alternate GUI way to do the same:

1. First, open Software & updates app.

   ```
   sudo apt install software-properties-gtk
   sudo software-properties-gtk
   ```
2. Then navigate to *other sources* → *Kubuntu CDrom.*
   The name may not be the same, you just need to uncheck anything which says "CDrom" or similar to it.
3. Uncheck it or remove it.
4. Update:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

That's it! 
Good Luck!